# sql strip http and https

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a column in my table named `url`.

I need to strip the url to the url without `http://` and `https://`

The problem is they are mixed. Some of them have http and some of them have https

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following, using [`REPLACE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql):

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(url, 'https://', ''), 'http://', '') AS url FROM table_name
```

In case you need to `UPDATE` your table, you can use the following:

```
UPDATE table_name SET url = REPLACE(REPLACE(url, 'https://', ''), 'http://', '')
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the following:

```
update t
    set url = (case when url like 'https://%'
                    then stuff(url, 1, 8, '')
                    when url like 'http://%'
                    then stuff(url, 1, 7, '')
                    else url
               end)
    where url like 'https://%' or url like 'http://%';
```

The difference between this an using `replace()` is that this only specifically removes the prefix at the beginning of the string.  This can be important if the URL contains additional keyword elements or indirections.